# Session timer and pass username to end page

Tags: php, html

How can I display the username selected from a drop down list on the first page and display the username on the last page with out passing variables one page by another? Plus, if I want to add a timer on a middle page and how can I put it into a php session and make the time elapsed appear on the end page with username. Thank you!
here is the code of log-in page

```
<p id="Hello world 1"></p>
<input type="text" value="Hello world 1">
<center>Centre Name
<select id="Centre_Name" id="Centre_Name" , name="Centre_Name">
<option value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
<option value="AAA">AAA</option>
<option value="BBB">BBB</option>
<option value="CCC">CCC</option>
<option value="DDD">DDD</option>
</select>
<a href="hello%20test%20file/Hello%20world%202.html"><input type="button"     id="btnQueryString" value="Submit" /></a>
```

2. the second page has a javascript function which records the current time.

```
<p id="Hello world 2"></p><br>
<button onclick="sessionstart()">start lesson</button>
<p id="starttime"></p>
<script>
function addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
var d = new Date();
    var x = document.getElementById("starttime");
    var a = addZero(d.getHours());
    var b = addZero(d.getMinutes());
function sessionstart() {
    x.innerHTML = a + ":" + b ;
}
</script>
<a href="file:///C:/Users/LLJ/Desktop/hello%20test%20file/Hello%20world%203.html"><input type="button" id="button"value="next" onclick="display_c(start)"></a>
```

Comment: Updates must be posted in the question not in comments (use the "edit" button).

Comment: I tried to use javascript to pass the value of variable, but it can only be done by passing from current page to next page, I wonder if this value can be sent directly to end page

Comment: I can also send the code from e-mail if you would like to help~ just leave the e-mail address. I will send all 5 pages of my html files. thank you!

Comment: If you want an help from the community (avoiding other downvotes) my suggestion is: update your question as I wrote previously and read ["How to ask a good question on SO"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for the future. PS: after the edit delete the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On **Page 1**, put your drop down and submit in a form. Direct the submit to page 2.

```
<form action="page2.php" method="POST">
    //your dropdown
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php
    session_start();
    //clean out a possible previous session
    session_unset();
?>
```

On **Page 2**, start a php session with `session_start()` and 
store the posted value in a session_var:

```
<?php 
    //DON'T forget to sanitize your $_POST variables!!!
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['myvar1']=$_POST['myvar1'];
    $_SESSION['myvar2']=$_POST['myvar2'];

    //if you want a timer
    $_SESSION['time_started']=time();

    echo $_SESSION['myvar1'];
    echo $_SESSION['myvar2'];

    echo '<a href="page3.php">goto page 3</a>';
?>
```

Now, as long as the user keeps his browser open, you have access to `$_SESSION['variable']` without the need to pass it trough every page:

**Page 3**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['myvar1'],$_SESSION['myvar1']){
        // ====> redirect to page 1
        }

    //check your timer: -900 is 15 minutes in seconds
    if($_SESSION['time_started']<time()-900){
         echo 'Too bad, it took you too long and now you failed';
         die;
         }

    echo $_SESSION['myvar1'];
    echo $_SESSION['myvar2'];

    echo '<a href="page3.php">let's page 4</a>';
?>
```

Comment: would you mind explain more in details, cause I am a bit confused right now, I tried your method but still failed in the end.

Comment: Have you created the form on Page 1, and can you retrieve the `$_POST` variable on Page 2?

Comment: I've extended my answer

Comment: thanks, but I am using html pages, is it okay if I switch all the php links to htmls?

Comment: or do I need to create a php file and call the function?

Comment: You tagged php. But basically the .php extention is an .html page that can run a script :-) So you can always use .php (if the webserver is up to it off course). So index.php and index.html are basically the same. Just change the names of your ~.html files in ~.php

Comment: Thank you. I got it. the function I mentioned cannot be done without using server-side programming language, so to speak.